# Confused with WP redirection

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I couldn't find any redirection URL in my WordPress code and but each time I completes the registration form it redirects to home page again. I need to change the redirection after the registration is complete. I can understand that the following code plays the trick but can any one help me how can I set the redirection to a URL from the below code and which part to replace?

Thanks

```
        if ( 'publish' == $status ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( add_query_arg( 'updated', 'true', get_permalink( $campaign ) ) );
        exit();
    } elseif ( 'submit' == $action ) {
        $url = isset ( $edd_options[ 'submit_page' ] ) ? get_permalink( $edd_options[ 'submit_page' ] ) : get_permalink();

        $redirect = apply_filters( 'atcf_submit_campaign_success_redirect', add_query_arg( array( 'success' => 'true' ), $url ) );
        wp_safe_redirect( $redirect );
        exit();
    } else {
        wp_safe_redirect( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink( $campaign ) ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'atcf_shortcode_submit_process' );

/**
 * Redirect submit page if needed.
 *
 * @since Astoundify Crowdfunding 1.1
 *
 * @return void
 */
function atcf_shortcode_submit_redirect() {
    global $edd_options, $post;

    if ( ! is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) )
        return;

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ( isset( $edd_options[ 'submit_page' ] ) && $post->ID == $edd_options[ 'submit_page' ] ) && isset ( $edd_options[ 'atcf_settings_require_account' ] ) ) {
        $url = isset ( $edd_options[ 'login_page' ] ) ? get_permalink( $edd_options[ 'login_page' ] ) : home_url();
        $url = add_query_arg( array( 'redirect_to' => get_permalink( $edd_options[ 'submit_page' ] ) ), $url );

        $redirect = apply_filters( 'atcf_require_account_redirect', $url );

        wp_safe_redirect( $redirect );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'atcf_shortcode_submit_redirect', 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You've many `wp_safe_redirect` functions.

Some outside the `atcf_shortcode_submit_redirect()` and one inside of it.

*However I'm not sure really* based on your code, those outside don't have anything to do with registration page. So you should change the one that is inside.

and that's the first `$url` variable:

```
$url = isset ( $edd_options[ 'login_page' ] ) ? get_permalink( $edd_options[ 'login_page' ] ) : home_url();
```

As you can see if there is no option saved before with the name of `login_page` redirection URL will be `home_url()` that's your homepage link.

If you wan't to redirect the user to login page, you'd better go and find this option (somewhere in related plugin/template settings page) and **check/fill** that option, otherwise change the `home_url()` to whatever local URL you want (*e.g. `"http://mywebsite/successful-page"`*)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the plugin (or theme) works internally before see the whole code, but I get a bit of sense.

wp_safe_redirect redirects to the given url(string). So try tinkering on that one. Keep copy and change the wp_safe_redirect parameter to 'https://google.com' or something else. Then you will find which conditional statement is triggering and redirecting to your homepage.

I think the atcf_shortcode_submit_redirect function redirects whom didn't logged in to login page, so it would not relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i like to use the javascript document.location.
 just write an function with single argument inside the function provide javascript code with script tags

```
function redirect($location)
{
//inside the function place the script code 
}
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.location = "here will be your local variable";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but in case anyone else is looking for the answer, here's what I did.

I was able to successfully redirect the user to the profile page by changing the $redirect value. However, when the user logged out, it would stay on the profile page and add the login/register into that page???

Anyways, I installed Peter's Login Redirect and set only 2 options:
"All Other Users" set the logout URL to the whatever page you want
"Post-Registration URL" set this to the page that should come up after a successful registration